# Return multiple values in one function in C with pointers

Tags: c, return-value

I've searched the internet for my problem but it won't get solved. 
I have the following function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int solve(double a, double b, double c, double *x1, double *x2){
    *x1=(-b+sqrt(pow(b,2)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a);
    *x2=(-b-sqrt(pow(b,2)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a);
}

int main(void){
    double a, b, c;
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    scanf("%lf", &b);
    scanf("%lf", &c);
    double x1, x2;
    int count= solve(a, b, c, &x1, &x2);
    if(!count){
        printf("no solution");}
    else if(count==1){
        printf("one solution x: %lf", x1);}
    else if(count>1){
        printf("two solutions x1: %lf x2: %lf", x1, x2);}
}
```

the program should return both values from the function *solve* but everytime I start the program I have a warning that says "missing return value". Where is my fault?
By the way *struct* is not an option cause of restrictions from my professor and it need to be all done in one function.

Comment: You declared your function as returning an `int` but you're not returning anything (there's no `return` statement).

Comment: 1. Your professor’s restrictions are a *terrible* idea in a real environment, but might theoretically serve some educational purpose. 2. You declare `solve` as returning an `int` using the regular return value (in addition to whatever it does with the output parameters), but you never actually do that. You can do that with `main` because it’s special-cased to mean 0, but for any other function that’s undefined behavior.

Comment: How does the function communicate to the caller that there is only one solution if `b`² = `4*a*c`? How does it communicate that there is no solution if `b`² < `4*a*c`? The `main` function is expecting the regular return value to be the number of solutions, but the `solve` function doesn’t calculate that information, and just leaves it as NaN for no solution or equal values for one solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int solve(double a, double b, double c, double *x1, double *x2){
    if((pow(b,2)-(4*a*c)>=0)){
        *x1=(-b+sqrt(pow(b,2)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a);
        if(sqrt(pow(b,2)-(4*a*c)>0)){
            *x2=(-b-sqrt(pow(b,2)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a);
            return 2;
        }    
        return 1;   
    } 
    else{
        printf("it is imaginary term, ");
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    double a, b, c;
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    scanf("%lf", &b);
    scanf("%lf", &c);
    double x1, x2;
    int count= solve(a, b, c, &x1, &x2);
    if(!count){
        printf("no real solution");}
    else if(count==1){
        printf("one solution x: %lf", x1);}
    else if(count>1){
        printf("two solutions x1: %lf x2: %lf", x1, x2);}
}
```

You have to design if condition in solve function so it will calculate the x2 value. And if you want to reduce size you can also use char data type for count variable.

Answer (score 5):

So, there's some misunderstanding here.
From what I can understand from the template code, your `solve` function is supposed to be returning the number of (real) solutions for a quadratic equation, and there's currently no logic for that.

You should implement logic that `return`s the number of solutions based on the input.
For a quadratic equation, you look at the discriminant. This is `b^2 - 4*a*c`.
If it is less than 0, there are no solutions, one solution if it's equal to 0, and two solutions otherwise.

Additionally, since there is no (real) square root of a negative number, you should not even run the calculations if the discriminant is less than 0.
If you run your function with `a*c > b^2`, `x1` and `x2` would be [Not a Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

You are performing the "return" of values using pointers correctly.
However, since your function is defined as `int solve`, it is expecting you use `return <some value>;` inside the function.
In fact, theoretically `int main` should be breaking it as well because you don't return anything (usually just `return 0`), but that's a special exception in the language to drop it for `main`.

Comment: On almost all platforms (those that support NaN), there’s no reason other than performance to avoid performing the calculation if there’s no solution. In fact, it might be good to do it either way so the outputs are NaN instead of unchanged or unspecified.

Comment: @DanielH Makes sense, although I'd argue handling NaN would probably confuse someone new to programming.

Answer (score -1):

You should return an int value in solve function, as your functions signature is: int solve(double a, double b, double c, double *x1, double *x2),so just add "return 0;" at the end of solve function.

Comment: If you're returning a value that does nothing, you should just be using `void solve`.

Comment: Or at least return 1 if nothing went wrong, 0 for an error (for example)